# If $\int_{y=0}^{y=b}\int_{x=0}^{x=a}f(x,y)dxdy=ab$, what is $f(x,y)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If $\int_{y=0}^{y=b}\int_{x=0}^{x=a}f(x,y)dxdy=ab$, for all $a,b$ between $0$ and $1$, what is $f(x,y)$?

I know that the answer is 1. But I want to know how you would get there, if you didn't know that.

This question popped into my brain when I was reading a blurb on copulas and the author gave a toy example of a copula he called the 'product copula', where the CDF version is $C(x,y)=xy$ and he stated the PDF version is $c(x,y)=1$. I took a moment to realize (intuitively) this is true. Then I wondered how it could be established if that answer wasn't given. So?

PS: if you don't know what a copula is (don't worry about it) but you do know how to answer this question, please do!

Comment: Please check your question in the title you say $ab$ and in the question you say $xy$

Comment: Why is it that x,y appear both bounded and unbounded in your equation?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense: The left is a fixed number, while the right is not.

Comment: Did you mean $\int_{y=0}^b\int_{x=0}^a \,f(x,y)dx\,dy=ab$?

Comment: @grand_chat, yes you are correct. I have fixed the typo.

Comment: I would try applying $\partial^2/\partial a \partial b$ to the equation.

Comment: I don't know what copula is, but I know you have to assume $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @GEdgar, I think I see the solution now. My brain block was in thinking that a pdf, is simply the first derivative of a cdf. But really you need to take as many derivatives as there are dimensions, once with respect to each dimension. Have I got that right?

Comment: Although so far you have not said whether you want this to be true for all $a,b$ that would have to be the case otherwise there are many counterexamples, such as, for example $f(x,y)=\left(1+\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{a}\right)\right)\left(1+\sin\left(\frac{2\pi y}{b}\right)\right)$.

Comment: Does the equality hold for all $a,b$?

Comment: I forgot to add that a copula is defined on a unit hypercube. So a and b are between 0 and 1.

Comment: Still no answer to the question whether it must be true for ALL $a,b$ between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Yes, all $a,b$ between $0$ and $1$

Comment: You should add "for all $a,b$ between $0$ and $1$" to the question, otherwise the conclusion does not follow.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, it is done!

Comment: @SimpleArt How does $\int_0^b \int_0^a (0) dx dy = ab$?

Comment: @jim My bad.  ${}$